# How to get all string matching regex1 followed by a string?

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I have a large text file.  I'd like to pick out strings of form

```
(1, 2, 4, ...)
```

which is followed by string "foobar".  Both of these two strings can appear on multiple lines. How to do this quickly on UNIX command line?

Example

```
(1, 2) foobar
foobar (3, 4, 5) foobar (23, 45) 
(6,
7, 8) foobar
(9, 10, 11) foo
bar
```

should give

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
(9, 10, 11)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a line that should match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ tr -d '\n' <input | grep -oP '\([^()]*\)(?= foobar)'
(1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6,7, 8)
(9, 10, 11)
```

Comment: Here's the `sed` pipe to neaten the output: `sed 's/, */, /g'`

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`. It slurps all the content of the input file in a scalar variable and with a regular expression checks for any group of numbers between parentheses followed by a literal `foobar`, and print each match.

```
perl -e '
    chomp( @s = <> );
    $s = join q||, @s;
    printf qq|%s\n|, $1 while $s =~ m/(\((?:,?\s*\d+\s*)+\))\s*foobar/g;
' infile
```

With this content of `infile`:

```
(1, 2) foobar
foobar (3, 4, 5) foobar (23, 45) 
(6,
7, 8) foobar
(9, 10, 11) foo
bar
```

Output will be:

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6,7, 8)
(9, 10, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/(/!d;s/(/\n&/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;:a;$!{/) foobar/!N;/) foobar/!ba};s/\n//g;s/\(([^)(]*)\) foobar/\n\1\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;P;D' file
```

Explanation:

- `/(/!d` delete lines without a `(`
- `s/(/\n&/` prepend a newline to the first `(`
- `s/^[^\n]*\n//` delete all characters upto and including the first newline.
- `:a` placeholder
- `$!{/) foobar/!N;/) foobar/!ba}` if not last line check for `) foobar` if not append next line, if still not `) foobar` loop to `a`.
- `s/\n//g` delete all newlines.
- `s/\(([^)(]*)\) foobar/\n\1\n/` surround intended string with newlines.
- `s/^[^\n]*\n//` delete all characters upto and including the first newline.
- `P` print first line
- `D` delete first line